# WP7 list width issue when orientation changs

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-interface, mobile

I want to make a dynamic filling list that fill the screen what ever the content is
so here what I did:
first: the design

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="25" Margin="0,10,0,0" BorderThickness="1" Background="Aqua">
 <Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Button Width="100" Name="RED"  Height="100" Click="ButtonDec_Click">
    <Button.Background>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="/LifeCounter;component/Images/RED.png" />
    </Button.Background>
   </Button>
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
   <TextBlock Name="name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAA" Foreground="{Binding color}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" />
   <TextBlock Name="count" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="CCCCC" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30" />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Name="GREEN"  Height="100" Click="ButtonInc_Click">
    <Button.Background>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="/LifeCounter;component/Images/Green.png" />
    </Button.Background>
   </Button>
  </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
</Border>
```

and the result was an item that fill the screen and doesn't matter in portrait or landscape

[image: case 1, the design without being bound]

and to make it dynamic, simply I made a list of data template

```
 <ListBox  Grid.Row="1" Name="countersList" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="countersList_SelectionChanged">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="25" Margin="0,10,0,0" BorderThickness="1" Background="Aqua">
     <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
       <Button Width="100" Name="{Binding index}"  Height="100" Click="ButtonDec_Click">
        <Button.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="/LifeCounter;component/Images/RED.png" />
        </Button.Background>
       </Button>
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
       <TextBlock Name="name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="{Binding color}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" />
       <TextBlock Name="count" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding count}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30" />
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
       <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Name="{Binding index}"  Height="100" Click="ButtonInc_Click">
        <Button.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="/LifeCounter;component/Images/Green.png" />
        </Button.Background>
       </Button>
      </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
    </Border>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

the result was a list that wrap it's size with it's content 
[image: after the binding]

so, how can I fix it, I want a list that fill the screen and it doesn't matter was it in landscape or portrait

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that the item in the listbox isn't stretched.

A listbox item's size is NOT determined by the ItemTemplate but by the ItemContainerStyle and the size of the ListBox.

First add to the ListBox:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ...>
```

to make sure the ListBox itself is stretched horizontally. If you set it at `Center` it will only become as wide as its content/children request for.

Then add this to the ListBox:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This ItemContainerStyle will cause all Items to be stretched to the width of the parent (ListBox's Item Panel)

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working as expected.
and sorry for the long post :)